# How to reset values of react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

I've been using the MERN stack. 
 I want to know how to reset values in redux values. 
 If I send incorrect data to backend `/login` route and I get `'Invalid email or password'` and I save it redux. I see that in the front-end. When changing the route and after I change the route to the login (react) page I see this message. If I refresh the page redux reset. 
 I have a question how to reset value **without refresh** and **change route**?

Comment: Set the initial state when loading the login component?

Comment: Get your desire data to the redux (initial data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I got from your question is you want to clear the **'Invalid email or password'** fro your redux store when you are switching from **page a** to **page b**.

This is what you can do is you reset to '' your data in redux by creating and action and dispatch it on unmounting inside *page a*.

something like this inside **page a**

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  dispatch(resetErrorMessageAction())
}
```

Inside **actions.js**

```
function resetErrorMessageAction(data) {
  return {
    type: 'RESET_ERROR_MESSAGE'
  }
}
```

Inside your reducer

```
function(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'RESET_ERROR_MESSAGE':
      return {
        ...state,
        errorMessage: ''
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do that is. But I write many code. I only want to add some code somewhere for when change route reset value

Answer (score 0):

```
import {reset} from 'redux-form';
```

...

```
dispatch(reset('myForm'));  // requires form name
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding it correctly then your problem is that after one dispatch (api call with redux) your redux state gets some data and when you dispatches another time then you are getting previously stored redux value, Just like the situation in which i am currently.

When i have logged out then then my redux got a value "logout successfully" and without refreshing the browser i am logging in then i am getting 2x "logout succesfully".

Here is a simple way to avoid this :-

step 1 :- create another reducer case after your previous ones and just clear them when your desired work completed.

```
.addCase('clearRedux', (state) => {
    state.error = null;
    state.message = null;
});
```

step 2:- select the reducer in which you want to perform action

```
const { message: logoutMessage, error: logoutError } = useSelector((state)=>state.logoutWorker);
```

step 3 :- dispatch the case when its needed

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (logoutMessage) {
      alert.success(logoutMessage);
      dispatch(loadWorker());
      dispatch({
        type: 'clearRedux'
      });
    }

    if (logoutError) {
        alert.error(logoutMessage);
        dispatch({
            type: 'clearRedux'
        });
    }
}, [dispatch, logoutMessage, logoutError]);
```

I hope your error will get resolved have a great coding day #eat_sleep_code_repeat.